# UIButton doesn't update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm trying to change the hidden property of a button and this is done in a method (View one):

```
-(void)changeSong:(NSString *)songName {

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:songName ofType:@"mp3"]];
    musicPlaying = YES;
    playButton.hidden = YES;
    pauseButton.hidden = NO;    
}
```

This method is called from another view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MainMenuController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
    [mainMenu changeSong:[songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    mainMenu = nil;
    [mainMenu release];

    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I know that the changeSong method is being called correctly because the music changes. However, the hidden property of the items don't change. I've tried calling [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; but this doesn't do anything.

Thanks

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the playButton.hidden line in the changeSong method, is playButton nil (0x0), or does it have an actual value?  If it is nil, you probably just neglected to wire up the UIButton to the playButton ivar in Interface Builder.

Comment: The value is nil as shown here: http://d.pr/7rrU but it's linked up in Interface builder: http://d.pr/z2B

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the MainMenuController hasn't finished initializing by the time you call -changeSong, which is why everything in MainMenuController is nil.

To solve this, either delay your call to -changeSong by using

```
[mainMenu performSelector:@selector(changeSong:) withObject:[songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] afterDelay:0.01];
```

or make your tableview the MainMenuController's delegate, and when MainMenuController is finished loading from the nib (using - (void)awakeFromNib in MainMenuController), call the delegate's method to change the song.

Since you're delaying the call in both cases, you'll have to be careful not to release the view controller before you do, so you'll have to change that code a little.

Comment: The perform selector solution didn't work so I'm going to try and use the delegate method when I get up tomorrow. I'll let you know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing a view controller from a nib using `-initWithNibName:bundle:`, the actual view and its subviews aren't unarchived until the first time the view controller's `view` property is accessed, per the documentation:

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the first time the view controller’s view is accessed. If you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded, override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there.

Try calling `[mainMenu view]` right after you initialize it from the nib. That will hydrate the view hierarchy from the nib.

However, I guess I don't understand why you're unarchiving a view controller from a nib and calling one of its methods that affects the UI (i.e., hiding or revealing buttons) without pushing that view controller to a navigation controller or presenting it modally. `-changeSong:` is a method on `MainMenuController`, so simply calling it right after you initialize `MainMenuController` won't have any effect on the buttons that it manages.

(Unrelated: You're setting `mainMenu` to `nil` before releasing it, which effectively means `mainMenu` can never be released. Call `-release` first, then, optionally, set it to `nil`.)

Comment: After playing around with it the problem was with:                 

[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

I've now changed it to  

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenu animated:YES];
     
but this makes the view move to the right, rather than to the left. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: There's no way to adjust the direction a navigation controller animates view controllers; doing so would be inconsistent with the overall user experience people come to expect. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? When the user selects a cell, you want to do something and then go back to the previous view controller?